# Angular kendo-dropdownlist value binding - control changing value on selection

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui-angular2

I use the Kendo UI for Angular DropDownList
I want to control the value so that it does not change automatically on selected, but I can control it manually.

Their [official documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/value-binding/) say as follows:

> Use the value property. If the value is set through the value
> property, you have to hook up to the valueChange event and manually
> update the value of the value property.

Cool, except for a small problem, it just does not work, it still changes automatically.

Here is the code:

html

```
<kendo-dropdownlist
         [data]="relationTypes"
         [textField]="'display'"
         [valueField]="'order'"
         [value]="row.relation_type"
         (valueChange)="handleRelationTypeChange(row,$event)">
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

ts

```
   public handleRelationTypeChange(row, $event) {
     this.MyService.updateRelationType($event.order).then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            row.relation_type = $event;
        },
        (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

Only if the server returns a successful response, I will change manually.
The problem is, as mentioned, that it changes automatically, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after many attempts, the answer seems simple.
Too bad there is no example on the [site](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/value-binding/).

I guess this will help many others, so:

To prevent an automatic change of `value`, what I had to do was, change the value binding from

```
<kendo-dropdownlist
     [data]="relationTypes"
     [textField]="'display'"
     [valueField]="'order'"
     [value]="row.relation_type"
     (valueChange)="handleRelationTypeChange(row,$event)">
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

To tow way binding:

```
<kendo-dropdownlist
     [data]="relationTypes"
     [textField]="'display'"
     [valueField]="'order'"
     [(value)]="row.relation_type"
     (valueChange)="handleRelationTypeChange(row,$event)">
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```